# tp-link wn722n doesnt appear in lsusb in kali linux not running in virtual box

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, lsusb

Today i bought a tp-link TL-WN722N for my kali machine
but when i plugged it into it, it doesnt appeared in wlan0. So i checked the lsusb and it also isnt there.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:010c  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05c6:f00e Qualcomm, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:08c7 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam OEM Cisco VT Camera II
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

the first one is the one is the wifi adapter
till now i have downloaded backports-4.4.2.1 and ran make but it doesnt do anything

```
make[5]: 'conf' is up to date.
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
Building backport-include/backport/autoconf.h ... done.
  CC [M]  /home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/main.o
In file included from /home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/backport-include/backport/backport.h:7:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common/include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h: In function ‘__qrwlock_write_byte’:
/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/backport-include/linux/kconfig.h:25:28: error: implicit declaration of function ‘config_enabled’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 #define IS_BUILTIN(option) config_enabled(option)
                            ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common/include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h:156:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘IS_BUILTIN’
  return (u8 *)lock + 3 * IS_BUILTIN(CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common/include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h:156:37: error: ‘CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  return (u8 *)lock + 3 * IS_BUILTIN(CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN);
                                     ^
/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/backport-include/linux/kconfig.h:25:43: note: in definition of macro ‘IS_BUILTIN’
 #define IS_BUILTIN(option) config_enabled(option)
                                           ^~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common/include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h:156:37: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  return (u8 *)lock + 3 * IS_BUILTIN(CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN);
                                     ^
/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/backport-include/linux/kconfig.h:25:43: note: in definition of macro ‘IS_BUILTIN’
 #define IS_BUILTIN(option) config_enabled(option)
                                           ^~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common/scripts/Makefile.build:298: recipe for target '/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/main.o' failed
make[8]: *** [/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/main.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common/scripts/Makefile.build:549: recipe for target '/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/compat' failed
make[7]: *** [/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1/compat] Error 2
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-common/Makefile:1507: recipe for target '_module_/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1' failed
make[6]: *** [_module_/home/keshav/Desktop/backports-4.4.2-1] Error 2
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[5]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile.build:6: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile.real:88: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

and i am using kali linux 4.9.0 and it is NOT running inside a virtual machine it is my stand alone os